# Android App with Broadcast receiver after reboot as main

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hello i would to develop a simple app without Main Activity as launcher.

I want to register a broadcast receiver which starts after reboot of device and inside OnReceive callback starts an Activity

Here my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="it.examples"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
        >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">


        <receiver android:name=".AfterRebootBR" android:exported="false" 
    android:label="Boot Notification Receiver" android:enabled="true"
         android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

               <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here my Broadcast receiver

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package it.examples;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class AfterRebootBR extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("AfterRebootBR","***************** ON RECEIVE *********************");
        Log.e("AfterRebootBR","***************** ON RECEIVE *********************");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i); 

    }

}
```

And finally the MainActivity

```
package it.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

Francesco

Comment: do you mean the `onReceive` never fired?

Comment: yes OnReceive never fired? i add a log line and an Toast message but not appear. Broadcast works only if is present an Activity with a typical intent filter (action=android.intent.action.MAIN and category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)

Answer (score 1):

my code is working..here is it...

in manifest

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.calender.calenderevent.Reboot_Reciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for for the answer but also trying your solution for not works. Can you post your manifest file? for me you have an activity  with a typical intent-filter (action=android.intent.action.MAIN and category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)

Comment: I changed the part of my manifest file like you suggested but the method OnReceive not is called after reboot

Answer (score 0):

I cant see anything wrong with your code, however i have something worth to try.

Move the permission out of the `application` tag  :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

If its not working, simplify the `receiver` :

```
    <receiver android:name=".AfterRebootBR">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Still not working? Try to add some delay, as mentioned [here](http://zadjhu.blogspot.sg/2013/08/better-to-add-some-delay-before.html) :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //run your service
            }
        }, 10000);
```

Quoted from the link above :

> While, I suggestion to delay several seconds, e.g., 10 seconds, before
>   running the (1) line, which is more stable for different phones and
>   services.
>
> For example, in my case, my service is going to write sd card. If you
>   start your service immediately, some phones may fail because the sd
>   card is not ready.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with android 3.1 you cannot have a broadcast receiver to get spawned by the application service manager if it has no context in active state (aka. at least an activity or service that is keeping the process in an "active state")

Excerpt from specification

```
Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents. 
It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or 
unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. A background service or 
application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES 
flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications.

Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet 
launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).
```

You need to somehow start your application, and then send it in a dormant state (but registered in the app manager). You can use a service for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly NOT recommended to start Activity from BroadcastReciever:
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html#ReceiveStatus

> Never start an Activity in response to an incoming broadcast Intent.

In my case **PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP** helped:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I've experimented with MIUI 8 firmware real device Xiaomi Redmi Note 3.

My findings are:

- you have to add app to autorun to enable it be fired by broadcast. I've checked it with such serious apps as Viber, WhatsApp.
- I've compared with manifest settings (without enabling reciever programmatically):

  `<receiver
          android:name=".activities.broadcastrecievers.CallReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
          </intent-filter>`